# How to append particular input field one by one onClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks, es6-modules

I have a function react component which has an object consisting of different values that renders in react form.

```
const initialInputValues = {
  domain: '',
  title1: '',
  title2: '',
  title3: '',
  title4: '',
  title5: '',
  title6: '',
  title7: '',
  description1: '',
  description2: '',
};

const [values, setValues] = useState(initialInputValues);

//handling input
const handleInputChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;

  setValues({...values, [name]: value });
}

//handle submit
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

I have a reusable FormGroup component like this

```
<FormGroup
  label='Domain'
  name='domain'
  type='url'
  value={values.domain}
  onChange={handleInputChange}
/>
<FormGroup
  label='Title 1'
  name='title1'
  value={values.title1}
  onChange={handleInputChange}
/>
<FormGroup
  label='Title 2'
  name='title2'
  value={values.title2}
  onChange={handleInputChange}
/>
<FormGroup
  label='Title 2'
  name='title2'
  value={values.title2}
  onChange={handleInputChange}
/> 
<FormGroup
  label='Title 3'
  name='title3'
  value={values.title3}
  onChange={handleInputChange}
/>
```

I have a button under this FormGroup Title fields, now I want to append `title4`, `title5`, `title6`, `title7` one by one on click of this Add button.

```
<button
  className='button__addField'
  type='button'
  onClick={handleAddTitle}
>
  Add Title
</button>
```

Is there any other way except using `useRef` and hide/show using CSS classes? I have tried that but looks like that is not a feasible solution if in future I want to expand title fields up to 12 or description fields up to 8 etc.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-estrela-r84fv3?file=/src/App.js:2517-2534

Answer (score 1):

Save the number of title fields in a state and create an array of components with the length of that state.

You don't need to change `handleInputChange` since it'll just merge the new name properties to the state.

[image: Edit hungry-lake-8njbo0]

```
export default function App() {
  const initialInputValues = {
    domain: "",
    title1: "",
    title2: "",
    title3: "",
    title4: "",
    title5: "",
    title6: "",
    title7: "",
    description1: "",
    description2: ""
  };

  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialInputValues);
  const [titleNum, setTitleNum] = useState(3)

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div className="sidebar-area">
      <form className="form-area" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form__buttons">
          <button className="button__share" value="Share" type="submit">
            Share
          </button>
          <button type="button" className="button__export">
            Export
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="form__heading">
          <div className="heading__iconTitle">
            <h4 className="heading__title">Campaign Basics</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <FormGroup
          label="Domain"
          name="domain"
          type="url"
          value={values.domain}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        {Array.from({length: titleNum}, (_,i, ind = i + 1) => (
          <FormGroup
          label= {`Title ${ind}`}
          name={`title${ind}`}
          value={values[`title${ind}`] || ''}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        ))}
        <div className="form__addField">
          <div>
            <button 
              className="button__addField" 
              type="button" 
              onClick={() => setTitleNum(prev => prev + 1)}
            >
              Add Title
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="form__group__inlineField">
          <FormGroup
            label="Path 1"
            name="path1"
            value={values.path1}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
          <FormGroup
            label="Path 2"
            name="path2"
            value={values.path2}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </div>
        <FormGroup
          rows="2"
          label="Description Line 1"
          name="description1"
          value={values.description1}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <FormGroup
          rows="2"
          label="Description Line 2"
          name="description2"
          value={values.description2}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are effectively wanting a dynamic list of titles then I'd suggest storing an array of titles in the state and appending to this array when you want to add another title input. You will want to use [functional state updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to correctly update from the previous `values` state value and not whatever `values` value is closed over in callback scope.

Example:

```
...
import { nanoid } from "nanoid"; // used for GUIDs

const MIN_TITLES = 3;
const MAX_TITLES = 7;

export default function App() {
  const initialInputValues = {
    domain: "",
    // Prepopulate titles array with minimum to display initially
    titles: Array.from({ length: MIN_TITLES}).map(() => ({
      id: nanoid(),
      value: ""
    })),
    description1: "",
    description2: ""
  };

  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialInputValues);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setValues((values) => ({ ...values, [name]: value }));
  };

  // Update title by id
  const handleTitleChange = (e) => {
    const { id, value } = e.target;
    setValues((values) => ({
      ...values,
      titles: values.titles.map((title) =>
        title.id === id
          ? {
              ...title,
              value
            }
          : title
      )
    }));
  };

  const addTitle = () => {
    setValues((values) => {
      // Shallow copy titles array and append new entry can still add
      if (values.titles.length < MAX_TITLES) {
        return {
          ...values,
          titles: values.titles.concat({
            id: nanoid(),
            value: ""
          })
        };
      }
      // Otherwise return previous state, no change
      return values;
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div className="sidebar-area">
      <form className="form-area" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        ...
        {values.titles.map((title, i) => (
          <FormGroup
            key={title.id}
            id={title.id}
            label={`Title ${i + 1}`}
            name={`Title${i + 1}`}
            value={title.value}
            onChange={handleTitleChange}
          />
        ))}
        <div className="form__addField">
          <div>
            <button
              className="button__addField"
              disabled={values.titles.length === MAX_TITLES}
              type="button"
              onClick={addTitle}
            >
              Add Title
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        ...
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Using arrays for these dynamic fields makes it trivial to add new fields, delete existing entries, and sort them later if necessary. In other words, storing the titles in an array makes them much easier to work with.

Similarly, if the plan is to eventually also make the "Path" and "Description" fields dynamic you would convert them also into arrays.

[image: Edit how-to-append-particular-input-field-one-by-one-onclick-in-react]